# data doesn't load instantly in drawer even though it's in same widget

Tags: flutter

So in my view I am fetching data whenever it inits.

```dart
  @override
  void initState()  {
    super.initState();
    context.read<UseAuth>().fetchUserInfo();
  }
```

After I display data in my app like `context.watch<UseAuth>().getNick` then it's all fine, however I have a drawer here as well and in that drawer I display `context.watch<UseAuth>().getAvatar`.
The drawer is in same widget.

But when I open the drawer, I don't see the avatar for like a 1-2 seconds.
I am not sure why this is happening?

Both are getters in my provider file, nick load instantly.

```
 String? get getNick => _userData?.nick;
 String? get getAvatar => _userData?.avatar_url;
```

I am using this in the drawer
`child: Image.network('${context.watch<UseAuth>().getAvatar}'),`. Should the image not be loaded already because drawer is in same Widget? Can this be happening because the Image.network?

Can I force this Image.network to load whenever the widget is loaded b efore opening the drawer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can load you image before accessing drawer, but you can use a package like https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image and have a placeholder for until the image is loaded. And also after first time loading, while the program will be running, the image will be cached.